# FBReaderJ integration

Tags: android, ant, epub

Who know some manual for [FBReaderJ](https://github.com/geometer/FBReaderJ) integration in another app? Maybe another tutorial for using Ant in Android Studio?

Comment: Do you find any solution?

Comment: no(( i think it's impossible

Comment: i know how to build it with android studio and gradle, will it help?

Comment: @Maxim Turaev  you can build it in android v studio the ice cream sandwich branch (Android 3 and above up to Android 8!)  or the older master branch (Android is ) ? The change in the GUI and features are big.  Have a look here : https://github.com/liquiddandruff/FBReaderJ/issues/1